# Pipe delimiter to generate CSV programmatically in apex

Tags: apex, list, csv

I am trying to generate CSV file with the `pipe |` as `delimiter` but the issue that I am facing is it is converting separator into `&#124;`

For example, if csv headers are contained in the list shown below and later if I try to join it using pipe `|`  using it outputs unexpected data.

```
List<String> listData = new List<String>{ 'Name' ,'ID', 'Stage'};
string.join(listData,'|');

output Name&#124;ID&#124;Stage instead of Name|ID|Stage
```

I tried to search so many threads but did not find any solution hence had to post it again

Comment: No, Apex doesn't do that (try this in an execute anonymous script, you'll see it comes out right). How are you attempting to render this string?

Comment: Double-check the concoding of the file, just in case

Comment: I guess it is the editor that shows the Pipe symbol as HTML encoded value `&#124;`